# Push to array based on other attributes

Tags: arrays, mongodb, push

Object structure (example only, there are thousands of callbacks in one object):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce82dd1eed5a17f33ec025a"),
    "id" : "AAA",
    "pac" : "",
    "callbacks" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ce82e29eed5a17f33ec0287"),
            "timestamp" : 1558720040,
            "type" : "data_bidir",
            "seqNumber" : 49,
            "messages" : [ 
                {
                    "isCode" : true,
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce82e29eed5a17f33ec0294"),
                    "key" : "action",
                    "value" : "extra_long_press"
                }, 
                {
                    "isCode" : false,
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce82e29eed5a17f33ec0293"),
                    "key" : "version",
                    "value" : "6"
                }, 
                {
                    "isCode" : false,
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce82e29eed5a17f33ec0292"),
                    "key" : "firmware",
                    "value" : "0.45"
                }
            ],
            "created" : ISODate("2019-05-24T17:47:21.476Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ce82e42eed5a17f33ec0295"),
            "timestamp" : 1558720040,
            "type" : "service_geoloc",
            "seqNumber" : 49,
            "messages" : [ 
                {
                    "isCode" : true,
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce82e42eed5a17f33ec029b"),
                    "key" : "lqi",
                    "value" : "Good"
                }, 
                {
                    "isCode" : false,
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce82e42eed5a17f33ec029a"),
                    "key" : "latitude",
                    "value" : "50.67593721530616"
                }, 
                {
                    "isCode" : false,
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce82e42eed5a17f33ec0299"),
                    "key" : "longitude",
                    "value" : "14.03118116624828"
                }, 
                {
                    "isCode" : false,
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce82e42eed5a17f33ec0298"),
                    "key" : "radius",
                    "value" : "8514"
                }, 
                {
                    "isCode" : true,
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce82e42eed5a17f33ec0297"),
                    "key" : "da_source",
                    "value" : "2"
                }, 
                {
                    "isCode" : true,
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce82e42eed5a17f33ec0296"),
                    "key" : "da_status",
                    "value" : "1"
                }
            ],
            "created" : ISODate("2019-05-24T17:47:46.547Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to push object to all messages only if a) callbacks.type is "service_geoloc" and  b) if messages contains key = da_source and value = 2 (in sample data - the second callback would be affected).

The condition a) is easily managed by arrayFilters:

```
db.getCollection("devices").updateMany(
  { id: 'AAA'},
  { $push: { 
    "callbacks.$[c].messages" : { 
        $each: [{key: "action", value: "atlas_position_network", isCode: true}],
        $position: 0
        }
    }     
  },
  { arrayFilters: [{"c.type": "service_geoloc"}], multi: true}
)
```

But I cannot figure out how to apply the condition b). I also tried elemMatch - it worked with both conditions but it updated only one message.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it in 2 steps. Maybe it is impossible to do it in one step using shell.

Step 1 = push the item into messages array with general value:

```
db.getCollection("devices").updateMany(
  { id: 'AAA'},
  { $push: { 
    "callbacks.$[c].messages" : { 
        $each: [{key: "action", value: "atlas_position_network", isCode: true}],
        $position: 0
        }
    }     
  },
  { arrayFilters: [{"c.type": "service_geoloc"}], multi: true}
)
```

Step 2 = Update the value based on other item on fixed position:

```
db.getCollection('devices').updateMany(
    { id: 'AAA' },
    { $set: { "callbacks.$[c].messages.0.value": "atlas_position_wifi"} },
    { arrayFilters: [{ "c.type": "service_geoloc", "c.messages.5.value": "6",  "c.messages.5.key": "da_source" }], multi: true }
)
```